# LinkButton needs to work like the Button of the Progress bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two forms - form1 and form2. Both the forms are a part of the progress bar. Form1 has a Next button. I need to perform 2 functions on the click of the Next button - One is to save all the data in form1 and the second is to move to form2. For the first function, I have a linkButton and for the second functtion, I have a button. But I need to merge these two functions in 1 button. How to do that?
asp code -

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-right: 300px;">Next
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class="btn btn-next" Text="Next" OnClick="FirstDataCapture" />
    </button>
```

c# code -

```
    protected void FirstDataCapture(object sender, EventArgs e)         
    {}
```

But when I am coming out of the FirstDataCapture function, the form 2 is going back to form1

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: can show some code what have you  tried?

Comment: any code so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two different function one for Saving data and second for moving to form 2.
and call both function on your button click event. first call function for data saving and then moving to form 2.
OR 
you can write both function code on your button click event.
like this

```
btn_clickEvent()
{
  // Code For Saving Data
  // Code For Moving to Form 2
}
```

Update

```
    protected void FirstDataCapture(object sender, EventArgs e)         
    {
      //Here First write code of data saving
      //Then after write code of moving on Form 2
    }
```

Comment: I need to have it written in c#

Comment: post some code what you have tried. So get better idea of It.